# Allow sorting on all resource's properties?

Tags: rest, sorting

I am designing a REST API for the first time and am implementing sorting.

Is a well-designed REST API supposed to allow sorting on each and every property or is it ok to limit sorting to only a subset of properties?

If a subset is ok, what do I do with a query asking to sort on another property: do I silently ignore this or should I throw/return 400?

Answer (score 0):

> Allow sorting on all resource's properties?

The usual answer is not to manipulate (sort) the representation of the resource, but instead to create a new resource that has a sorted representation.

```
GET /1a587d4e-4443-49ce-9195-20e821e67f83
```

```
GET /1a587d4e-4443-49ce-9195-20e821e67f83?sort=name
```

From the perspective of general purpose components, these are two *different* resources.  The might be completely independent of each other, or they might be different expressions of the same underlying data.

This works fine as long as you don't need the general purpose components's copy of the two different representations to always agree.  Because the resources have distinct identifiers, they will each have their own caching policies, and invalidating one will not necessarily invalidate the other.

An alternative approach that is sometimes used is to make the distinction part of the media-type, rather than part of the resource identifier

```
GET /1a587d4e-4443-49ce-9195-20e821e67f83
Accept: application/prs.unsorted+json
```

```
GET /1a587d4e-4443-49ce-9195-20e821e67f83
Accept: application/prs.name-sorted+json
```

In other words, use the content negotiation capabilities of HTTP to ensure that the client gets the appropriate representation.  That side steps some of the consistency problems that you might have, trading off against the additional complexity of "how does the client figure out which content-types to include in the Accept header.

> The gist of my question is: how to approach sorting a collection of resource, e.g. GET api/orders?sortby=createdOn. Do I need to allow sorting on any of the Order's properties or can I ignore the client's request to sort on some of them (e.g. GET /api/orders/sortby=itemCount

From the perspective of REST, that's entirely up to you.  The origin server is the authority for whether or not any given target-uri is meaningful (ie, whether or not that identifier is available at any given moment).

You get to decide whether there should be a resource to show orders sorted by last modification date, or order total, or discount, or whatever you like.

Comment: I have trouble understanding the answer. What is a "general purpose component"? What is a "general purpose components's copy of the two different representations"? The gist of my question is: how to approach sorting a collection of resource, e.g. `GET api/orders?sortby=createdOn`. Do I need to allow sorting on any of the `Order`'s properties or can I ignore the client's request to sort on some of them (e.g. `GET /api/orders/sortby=itemCount`)?

Comment: You have edited your response to take into account my comment. I consider the last two paragraphs of your answer to be relevant to my question.